# How to use SwiftyJSON to parse data with abiguous types?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have JSON structured like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value":["val1", "val2", "val3"]
    },
    {
      "value":"val"
    }
  ]
}
```

So how would I parse the "value" field here? Sometimes it is an array of strings and sometimes it is just a single string. What type would I assign to it?

Comment: Note that your JSON is invalid. You need quotes around the top-level key "data".

Comment: I haven't used swifty-json in a while. If you used JSONSerialization, you'd get "value" with a type of `Any`.

Comment: @DuncanC Fixed. I can assign the "Any" type but don't I still need to indicate if it is an array or not?

Comment: `Any` can be any type (including either a string or an array of strings.) You'd need to write code to interrogate it and handle each case separately.

Answer (score 2):

Using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) you can check if the value of the `value` property is a simple string or an array of strings like this:

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value":["val1", "val2", "val3"]
    },
    {
      "value":"val"
    }
  ]
}
"""
let json = JSON(parseJSON: jsonString)

json["data"].array?.forEach { dataItem in
    if let dataArray = dataItem["value"].array {
        print("array: \(dataArray)")
        print("array first item: \(dataArray.first?.string ?? "nil")")
    } else if let dataString = dataItem["value"].string {
        print("string: \(dataString)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And the datatype for "value" should be "Any" right?

Comment: @Arjun are you referring to your model object? If yes, `Any` is an option. Alternatively, may also be an array of strings which, in the second case, has only one string element. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you need to abstract the dictionary values in data array. Then, while accessing the objects you can type check of them, or you do the type check while decoding.

Here is my solution for this problem using native JSONDecoder. The important point is you need to provide decoder strict types of your objects. `Any, AnyObject` class do not conform `Decoder` protocol, since they do not have typed-container to decode.

```
enum B: Decodable {
    
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case value
    }
    
    enum BDecodingError: Error {
        case decoding(String)
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let val = try? container.decodeIfPresent(Array<String>.self, forKey: .value) {
            self = .array(val)
            return
        }
        if let val = try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value) {
            self = .string(val)
            return
        }
        
        throw BDecodingError.decoding("B Decoding Error")
    }
    
    case array(Array<String>)
    case string(String)
}
```

B enum is responsible for keeping the objects in dictionaries. You can specify the possible types here and check if decoding to that type is successful.

```
struct A: Decodable {
    let data: [B]
}
```

A struct simply holds the objects of your dictionary within `data` array.